# python encode() and decode() issues

Tags: python, python-3.x, decode, encode

Can anyone help me with this issue please
encode method is not working and i cannot discover why

```
def encode_OctetString(A,flags,data):
    fs="!"+str(len(data))+"s"
    dbg="Encoding String format:",fs
    logging.debug(dbg)
    ret=struct.pack(fs,data).encode("hex")
    pktlen=8+len(ret)/2
    return encode_finish(A,flags,pktlen,ret
```

error code

```
 File "/home/ubuntu/diameter-test/libDiameter.py", line 434, in encode_OctetString
    ret=struct.pack(fs,data).encode("hex")
struct.error: argument for 's' must be a bytes object
```

Comment: Please show us the whole error.

Comment: I just edited the question :)

Comment: Can you share the call of this function that actually caused the error? Also, the code you posted appears to have been cut short at `,ret`, since there is no closing parenthesis. And finally, what is `encode_finish`?

Comment: Can you include the full stack trace?

Comment: Note that `struct.pack()` will normally return a `bytes` and `bytes` don't have an `.encode()` method, just a `.decode()` one - were you trying to first decode and then re-encode as `"hex"`?

Comment: I previously posted the entire code, can you please give it a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70591196/struct-error-argument-for-s-must-be-a-bytes-object-python-to-python3

Comment: You're OK to link to another location and since it's on SO, it's not a problem, but generally a question and answer are most useful to all if the relevant code is included.

Comment: By the way, I think the answer below already addresses your issue, assuming the answer to my previous question is 'yes' (which I can't tell from the linked code).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that `struct.pack()` will normally return a `bytes` and `bytes` don't have an `.encode()` method, just a `.decode()` one - were you trying to first decode and then re-encode as `"hex"`?

If so, you'll need to import `codecs.encode()` and apply that to the `bytes` object:

```
import struct
import logging
import codecs


def encode_OctetString(A, flags, data):
    fs = "!" + str(len(data)) + "s"
    dbg = "Encoding String format:", fs
    logging.debug(dbg)
    ret = codecs.encode(struct.pack(fs, data), "hex")
    pktlen = 8 + len(ret) / 2
    return encode_finish(A, flags, pktlen, ret)
```

If you somehow intended `encode_OctetString` to work on strings instead of `bytes` objects, you'd use:

```
def encode_OctetString(A, flags, data):
    fs = "!" + str(len(data)) + "s"
    dbg = "Encoding String format:", fs
    logging.debug(dbg)
    ret = codecs.encode(struct.pack(fs, data.encode()), "hex")
    pktlen = 8 + len(ret) / 2
    return encode_finish(A, flags, pktlen, ret)
```

Given the link to the original code, that depends on the expected type for `AVP_Value` in `encodeAVP` - which is never called in the shared code, nor is its type documented and no type hint is provided, so it's impossible to say.

Edit (after accepted answer): it's important to note the difference between a string and a `bytes` object. Python makes them look very similar, after all `'hello'.encode()` just becomes `b'hello'`, right?

But they are very different. A string is a series of characters that have no specific encoding you have to worry about. So, `'hello'` is just an `'h'`, followed by an `'e'`, etc. - without you having to worry about what encoding is used to represent those characters in storage. However, `b'hello'` is a series of bytes with a specific encoding, that *could* be interpreted to mean a series of characters `'hello'` if they were decoded into a string using a known encoding (UTF-8 by default).

That's why, in this answer, `data` is encoded first (using UTF-8, as no encoding is specified), so that `struct.pack` can deal with it (it requires bytes, not a string) and the result is then re-encoded into a hex string representation using the "hex" encoding. That's often somewhat confusing, because although it's an encoding, the result is a string.

The takeaway should be that `bytes` are just bytes, that only have meaning if you decide what encoding they are in. Strings `str` are just abstract series of characters, the encoding is immaterial. Encoding means taking something with meaning and encoding it into binary that represents that content. Decoding means taking a bunch of binary code (bytes) and interpreting it back into something meaningful, like a string.

Comment: this gets closer but still isn't correct -- the error message is because `data` isn't `bytes` -- it doesn't get past the `pack(...)` call

Comment: @AnthonySottile `encode_OctetString` should only be called with `data` being a `bytes` object - if it's not, then there is no problem with the code presented, but with the code calling it. Unless the function was intended to work on `data` being a string.

Comment: I've updated the answer to provide an alternative - in either case, `codecs.encode` would allow for the `"hex"` encoding.

Comment: solved! thanks a lot

Comment: You're welcome - feel free to tick the answer as accepted to indicate the question has been answered, or post your own answer if there's something missing.

Comment: I will get back to you if anything went wrong and thanks one more time!

Comment: I don't think the comment section of a somewhat related question is a good place for a line-by-line debugging of a script in a different question. Have a look at the solution and try to understand why it solves the first problem - it looks like the second one is the same issue again.

Comment: I've added some explanation to the answer, maybe that helps.